# Button only on Safari browser is overlapping other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, safari

The issue I'm facing pertains to two buttons on our homepage: "View Product" and "Add to Cart." ONLY in **Safari**, the "Add to Cart" button appears to span the **entire width**, effectively overshadowing and making the **"View Product" button non-responsive** entirely; so if you attempt to press "View Product" within a Safari browser, it will instead select the "Add to Cart" button instead which is not intended. This problem seems isolated to Safari, as tests on other browsers show both buttons functioning as intended.
[image: As you can see there is clearly room for each button and other browsers have no issue with allowing the proper selection of either button]

If you have access to a Safari browser and rather troubleshoot this live on your Safari browser, this web app can be found at [CharmingButterfly](https://CharmingButterfly.com)

Here is the relevant segment of code:

```
                <main className="productItemMain">
                    <div className="itemH" spellCheck="false">
                          <Meta
                              title={`${title} - $${price}`}
                              description={`${description && description.substring(0, 40)}...`}
                              />
                              <div className="color-swatches">
                                  {product.colors.map((colorObj) => (
                                      <div
                                          key={colorObj.hue}
                                          className={`color-bubble ${selectedColor === colorObj.hue ? "selected" : ""}`}
                                          style={{ background: colorObj.hue }}
                                          onClick={() => handleColorSelect(colorObj.hue)}
                                      ></div>
                                  ))}
                              </div>
                              <div className="size-selector-box">
                                  {selectedColor && (
                                      <CustomDropdown
                                          options={product.colors.find(c => c.hue === selectedColor).sizes.map(sizeObj => sizeObj.size)}
                                          selected={selectedSize}
                                          onChange={(value) => setSelectedSize(value)}
                                      />

                                  )}
                              </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="productsButtons">
                       <div className="containerCoolBox">
                          <div className="containerCool">
                              <div className="centerCool">
                                <Link className="" to={`/product/${slug}`}>
                                  <button className="btnCool">
                                      <svg  height="50px" viewBox="0 0 180 75" className="borderCool">
                                           <polygon points="179,1 149,1 179,29" className="triangle" />
                                           <polyline points="179,1 179,74 1,74 1,1 179,1" className="bg-line svgBoxBtn" />
                                           <polyline points="179,2 179,74 2,74 2,2 179,2" className="hl-line svgBoxBtn" />
                                       </svg>
                                       <span className="coolProductTag">
                                           <EyeOutlined className="text-danger productCartIcon" /> 
                                           View Product
                                       </span>
                                  </button>
                                </Link>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div className="containerCoolBox">
                         
                           <div className="containerCool">
                               <div className="centerCool">
                                 <Tooltip title={tooltip}>
                                   <button
                                       className="btnCool"
                                       onClick={handleAddToCart}
                                       // Ensure product has quantity, color is selected and size is selected
                                      disabled={product.quantity < 1 || !selectedColor || !selectedSize || isOutOfStock()}
                                      style={{ opacity: selectedColor ? 1 : 0.5 }}
                                   ><svg  height="50px" viewBox="0 0 180 75" className="borderCool">
                                           <polygon points="179,1 149,1 179,29" className="triangle" />
                                           <polyline points="179,1 179,74 1,74 1,1 179,1" className="bg-line svgBoxBtn" />
                                           <polyline points="179,2 179,74 2,74 2,2 179,2" className="hl-line svgBoxBtn" />
                                       </svg>
                                       
                                       <span className="coolProductTag">
                                           <span>
                                               <ShoppingCartOutlined className="text-danger productCartIcon" />
                                               {product.quantity < 1 || isOutOfStock() ? "Sold Out" : "Add to Cart"}
                                           </span>
                                       </span>
                                   </button>
                                  </Tooltip>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
```

> 

To resolve this, I've first tried discovering a working debugging Safari browser emulator such as BrowserShack (working debugger but requires a costly subscription) and LambdaTest (doesn't work because it doesn't real time provide dom elements for debugging, only the pre-rendered dom elements of first load). So with both emulators not viable options i've been making numerous adjustments and have been testing the changes live on my mobile device; however this is basically me shooting in the dark and reading online documentation regarding Safari interaction with buttons and such. Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I'd be grateful for any insights or anyone with access to a Safari capable debugging browser and help me understand why my "Add to Cart" button is overlapping the "View Product" button unexpectedly.

Comment: Works fine in my version of Safari. I must say, though, that the site is very slow to load, and that fancy intro will just put people off. I know it's clever, but it's not good for business. The fan on my laptop was roaring and the page was jerking all over the place just trying to scroll the page. Sorry for the negative feedback, but I think you need to be told!

Comment: Thanks for checking, hmm well I'm now wondering if maybe the issue is mobile iPhone Safari specific? Also, yes page load optimization is on the to-do list as I'm not happy with it either right now.